# Why is it okay to swap a resistor and source in series?

Tags: circuit-analysis

I need some help understanding why it is okay to swap resistor and source in series in the following problem. Mesh analysis of the problem is rather easy, but the nodal analysis appears to have two super nodes. I was able to get the correct answer by switching the source and resistor so that the circuit looked like the second problem, however, I don't fully comprehend why switching them is permissible. In case it is necessary, the question is looking for the voltage at R3.

[image: Apparent Super Nodes]

[image: Super Nodes Resolved]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each of those two series elements, R1+V1 and R2+V2 are the same if you flip them, right? They still have the same current flowing down the leg, and the voltage drop across the V+R elements is the same in each leg.

The node **between** R1 and V1 will change depending on which way you flop them, but if you don't care about that node, nothing else in the circuit can even tell, right?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQJCkj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Another way to look at it:

$$V_a = R\times I + V_b$$

or

$$I = {(V_a-V_b) \over R}$$

Neither of these equation forms change if you change the positions of Vb and R!